# Do not know how to convert JArray(List(JString(dds3), JString(sdds))) into class java.lang.String

Tags: scala

```
 ~ pathPrefix("system") {
                post {
                  entity(as[JValue]) { system =>
                    val newPerms = for {
                      sitePerms <- findAllPermissions((system \ "siteId").extract[String])
                    } yield {
                      sitePerms.groupBy(_.userId).mapValues(_.map(_.permissionType).toSet)
                    }.flatMap { case (userId, perms) =>
                      val systemId = (system \ "id").extract[String]
                      perms.map(Permission(userId, systemId, _, "system"))
                    }

                    onComplete(newPerms.flatMap(addPermissions)) {
                      case Success(_) => complete(StatusCodes.NoContent)
                      case Failure(error) => failWith(error)
                    }
                  }
```

Request Body

```
[{
    "name": "dds3",
    "description": "",
    "siteId": "abs",
    "companyId": "local"
},
{
    "name": "dds3",
    "description": "",
    "siteId": "abc",
    "companyId": "local"
}]
```

Error:

```
The request content was malformed:
No usable value for name
Do not know how to convert JArray(List(JString(dds3), JString(sdds))) into class java.lang.String
```

I want to pass a List of array from request body but don't know how to do that in scala, can anyone please help me on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is to let the `entity` directive unpick your data for you:

```
case class System(
  name: String, 
  description: String,
  siteId: String,
  companyId: String,
)

entity(as[List[System]]) { system =>
```

`system` will contain a parsed list of `System` objects that can be processed in the usual way.